# Can't see my AFHTTPRequestOperationManager class after RestKit installation

Tags: restkit, afnetworking, cocoapods, restkit-0.20, afnetworking-2

I created new Xcode project and then I added some libraries to this project by using cocoa pods. In my pod file I mentioned following libraries.

```
platform:ios, '7.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.22'   <-- this one should contains AFNetworking
pod 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2'
```

During programming stuff I realised that Xcode can't find AFHTTPRequestOperationManager
and I'm wondering why, because other AFNetworking class works fine like for example AFHTTPRequestOperation or AFJSONRequestOperation.  Is there something that I should add to my pod file?
I tried to add standalone AFNetworking library by adding to my pod file the following line:

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
```

Then I get error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>   - `AFNetworking (~> 1.3.0)` required by `RestKit/Network (0.22.0)`- `AFNetworking (~> 2.0)` required by `Podfile`

It seems like during installing new version of RestKit which contain AFNetworking the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager class was omitted.

Please help me with fixing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`RestKit` is not yet working with `AFNetworking` 2.*, just add the older `AFNetworking` to your pod file:

```
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 1.3.0"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed the above version but still my Xcode can't see this class.